# How to read the variable value in nginx sent through post method?

Tags: ajax, post, nginx

I am making an ajax call that requests for some data. The request method is of type post.

Is there a way out to read the post variable value in location block of nginx?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably possible, but why not put it in request line instead (or as addition)?

Comment: Can you please explain in simple words?

Comment: You could send POST to url like `/my/api/?var=42` and in nginx there will be `$arg_var` variable with value `42`.

Comment: Actually I am using already made function where the request is made like /my/api. Please tell me if you know some other way out.

Comment: There is 3rd party modules like [FormInput](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFormInputModule) or [Lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_post_args), but its not really good idea to read POST body in nginx.

Comment: Can you give me an example of their usage for so?

Comment: Read the docs. There are plenty of examples.